# How can I automate the scenario when i want to login via google or facebook?

Tags: javascript, android, appium

I want to automate the scenario but I am not able to identify the element via appium Uiautomator is there any way I can handle the scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the elements on the screen using at least next 4 approaches:

1. Invoke [AndroidDriver.getPageSource()](https://appium.github.io/java-client/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--) function - it will return the source code of the current page and you will be able to get the "interesting" elements locators from there

   [image]
2. Use [Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor)

   [image]
3. Use [Appium Desktop Inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop#the-inspector) Session

   [image]
4. Use [Appium Stuidio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) which even provides `Copy Unique XPath` feature:

   [image]